# Why is creating cells using insertCell so slow?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to create 1500 rows dynamically, with each row having 4 cells. In Internet Explorer 11, it is taking too much time – 36 seconds. I used the browser’s profiler and found that the `insertCell` function itself took 30 seconds (in total, for all 1500×4 calls).

How can I improve the performance of my table-building function? Is there any alternative to `insertCell`?

```
function createRow(tableObj, newRowIndex, rowData, rowId) {
    var newCell, colID, newRow, i;

    newRow = tableObj.insertRow(newRowIndex);
    newRow.id = tableObj.id.replace(/DATATABLE/, "R" + rowId);
    colID = newRow.id + "C";
    for (i in rowData.Cells) { // rowData.Cells = 4
        if (rowData.Cells.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            newCell = newRow.insertCell(i);
            newCell.id = colID + i;
            newCell.className = "c" + rowData.Cells[i].id;
            newCell.innerHTML = rowData.Cells[i].data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try building the entire dom before inserting it into the page?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you make a change to the DOM the borwser has a lot of work to do. You should try to make those changes in bigger chunks to avoid repeating that work.

If your code for example creates elements by setting `innerHTML` then it's better to build the whole HTML string and set that (if possible). Javascript is fast... but the browser HTML parser is hand-optimized C++ code on which implementers invested a lot to make it as fast as possible.

If you instead work by creating elements and connecting event handlers to closures (something that can't be done by setting HTML) then it's better to build the whole thing outside of the DOM and insert it with `appendChild` only at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question. Did you perhaps try creating a single TR and then using cloneNode() and attaching it repeatedly. I'm guessing that the clone operation would at least create the cells in one operation.